# How to use custom fonts with Handlebars and Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I got a `Handlebar` template that I convert to PDF using `Puppeteer`. The question is how can I use custom fonts?

Currently I got a static folder in my `app.js` file declared like so: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));`. This contains the custom font.

In my Handlebar template I declare these fonts like so:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
      src: url("../assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf");
      font-style: normal;
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
      src: url("../assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Italic.ttf");
      font-style: italic;
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
      src: url("../assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf");
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    body {
      font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
      font-stretch: normal;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

But when generating the pdf, a standard font is loaded and not the custom font.

Comment: See the related github issue for more info - https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/422.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('file://C:/Path/to/yours/index.html', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    await page.pdf({
        path: 'test.pdf',
        printBackground: true,
        //more custom options here
    });
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Adding `{ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }` option works for me.

[https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/422](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/422#issuecomment-407297007)

[Puppeteer - page.goto(url[, options])](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.4.0&show=api-pagegotourl-options)