# Puppeteer & Handlebars - Custom Fonts

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, puppeteer, custom-font

I'm currently attempting to load custom font on a handlebar template using Puppeteer and I can't seem to get it to load custom fonts. The popular question here on stackoverflow [linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154854/how-to-use-custom-fonts-with-handlebars-and-puppeteer)
links to a popular Github issues page for Puppeteer [linked here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/422#issuecomment-407297007). I have tried everything in those two links to no avail. I've tried:

- `{waitUntil: 'networkidle0'} & {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}`
- ```
  await page.evaluateHandle('document.fonts.ready');
  ```
- ```
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
  ```
- ```
  await page.focus('body');
  ```
- ```
  await page.screenshot({path: 'tester.png'});
  ```
- ```
  const loaded = page.waitForNavigation({
            waitUntil: "load",
        })
  ```

From what I can tell on the Github issue, however, is that none of the posters are using Handlebars so that might be why they can get it to work. I noticed a few posters mention doing the HTML inline which I can't do with Handlebars. I've tried both local and online font files to no avail either. I've seen some posts mention using page.go to vs page.setContent like using setContent is the problem but I can't find how to use page.go with Handlebars. I'm also using VisualStudio code as the editor with WSL, not sure if that makes a difference.

Has anyone been able to get either online or local fonts to work with Puppeteer and Handlebars together?

I have this code in the app.js for the static folder:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'modules')))`

Here is what I have for code in the app.js file for Puppeteer:

```
async function convertToPDF() {

const extData = await extensionListPDFOrganize();

const compile = async function() {
    const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'extensionList.hbs');
    const html = fs.readFileSync(filePath, {encoding:'utf8'});
    return hbs.compile(html)(extData);
}
try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome'});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const content = await compile();

    await page.setContent(content);

    //THIS IS WHERE I INSERT THOSE SOLUTIONS IN THE BULLETS ABOVE

    await page.emulateMediaType('screen');
    await page.pdf({
        path: 'test.pdf',
        format: 'Letter',
        printBackground: true
    })

    console.log('done');
    await browser.close();
    process.exit();

}  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return(error);
}}
```

Here is the Handlebar css:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lasiver';
    src: url("../modules/fonts/Lasiver.otf");
    font-style: normal;
}
p {
    font-family: 'Lasiver';
}
</style>
```